# Network List Service hangs Windows 8.1 on startup

Tags: windows-8.1

Since upgrading my Windows 8 laptop to 8.1 RTM it seems to 'hang' with 100% disk usage for about 20 minutes. After that it works ok.

I've established that the Network List Service (`netprofm.dll`) is recreating 4 x 2Gb files in `C:\Windows\System32\networklist\icons`. Four files are created ending `_16.bin`, `_24.bin`, `_32.bin` and `_48.bin`. I guess these should be icons? If I delete them they are recreated at the next boot.

It's made my machine unusable. I've tried disabling the Network List Service in Services but it seems to still get started somehow. Any ideas how to stop this?

Andrew

Comment: contact the MSDN/Technet support or go back to 8 RTM. The 8.1 has issues that MS is aware of, so only use it if you really need it (update your apps to publish them into the store).

Comment: post your answer from Technet (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bebbd935-f6f8-47fb-b756-714c27f0da7d/win-81-rtm-slow-startup-thanks-to-network-list-service?forum=w81previtpro#911dca41-dca7-46c7-86b4-01f97b096d7a) here and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution thanks to Chad from The Defrag Tools on Channel 9. I found that I had two registry keys below  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures. One of the sub-keys had really long hex entries for Icon16/Icon24/Icon32/Icon48 (in total over 35,000 HEX characters). I exported the sub-keys and deleted them along with the four 2Gb files in C:\Windows\System32\networklist\icons. I'm pleased to report that normal reboot times have returned and the 4x2Gb files are not recreated. Please let me know if it fixes your problem.

Andrew